# IE SCRIPT1002 match function returns error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, syntax, syntax-error

I have a problem, my code works correctly in all browsers except IE.
IE returns me SCRIPT1002 Syntax error.
This line:
if(data.responseText.match(/Произошла.*/)) {
On next code:

```js
  localRequest: function(period, adapter, adapterType, errText){
            let _this = this;
            let iRow = rowInfo.iRow;
            let aboutRow = rowInfo.aboutRow;
            queryState = $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: 'api/ds/cs',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    period: period,
                    adapter: adapter,
                    adapterType: adapterType,
                    errText: errText,
                    subject: iRow.value,
                    body: aboutRow.value
                },
            }).done(function (data) {
 
            }).fail(function(data){
               **if(data.responseText.match(/Произошла.*/)) {**
                        let errText = data.responseText.split(')',)
                        let errNumb = errText[0].split('(',)
                   
                        alert('Не удалось сформировать проишествие: ' + errText[1] + ' №' + errNumb[1])
 
                    } else {
                        alert(data.responseText);
                    }
            })
        },
```

Comment: `.split(')',)` ... what's that trailing comma doing there? That's your problem

Comment: It cuts error text from the response

Comment: no, that comma is not cutting anything from anywhere ... that comma is a syntax error (in IE) ... calling a function like `fn(a,)` is tolerated by modern browsers, but it's syntactically incorrect and IE is telling you that it is wrong - do `.split(')')` instead and rejoice - or `.split(')', 1)` if you want to limit to one split

Comment: Thanks! I will try another function to take text inside ()

Comment: huh??? What?? just remove the `,` ..wow, you don't need a new function, you need to write syntactically correct code

Comment: Ok, I get it. Thanks

Comment: I agree with Jaromanda's comment. Does it help to solve your issue? If so, I think you can suggest Jaromanda to put it as an answer and you can accept the answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.